# How to make swapping between Debug/Release less painful in this cross-platform project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, cmake, vtk

We have a C++ CMAKE project. I work on it under Windows using Visual Studio 2019. My coworkers work under Ubuntu using QTCreator.

Here is what my current steps look like for swapping from a DEBUG build to a RELEASE build:

First set up VTK:

1. Open the release VTK build folder in Visual Studio and build the "INSTALL" subproject to overwrite the installed debug version of VTK with the release build.

Then set up our project:

1. Edit my account's PATH environment variable to point to the location of the new sub-project DLLs where Visual Studio will put them. (myProject\lib\analytics\Debug to myProject\lib\analytics\Release)

[image: Path editing]

Without telling Windows where the sub-project's DLLs are, trying to execute the program does not work. Not sure if there's a way to tell Visual Studio to look for the DLLs automatically.

2. Edit the top-level CMAKE of the project:

```
SET(BUILD_MODE Release)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RELEASE" CACHE STRING "Sets release build by default")
```

3. Open Cmake-GUI and clear the cache, then run "Configure" and "Generate"

If I do not clear the cache, Cmake Gui has consistently used older/incorrect settings resulting in unusual build issues.

4. Open the project under Visual Studio, changing the build type at the top to my new choice.
5. Hit "Rebuild" on ALL_BUILD.

With all those steps done, I have managed to swap from a Debug to a Release build.

Is there some way to simplify this process and make it easier to swap between the two?

I am not very familiar with Visual Studio or Cmake, so I'm not sure what functionality I'm missing out on.

Comment: I find [ccache](https://ccache.dev/) (with a *large* cache size) to be very helpful to speed up builds when switching between debug and unoptimized builds.

Comment: In Visual Studio which I use with CMake, Qt, VTK since 2008 at work I don't do any of the #2 steps or the #1 steps. I build for both Debug, Release and sometimes RelWithDebinfo in multiconfig and don't usually use the INSTALL target at all.

Comment: Why not having two build directories? One for debug and one for release. Maybe you have to call CMake manually from terminal (and passing CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE as an command line argument).

Comment: Btw: you may want to take a look at [cmake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) instead of introducing `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` for a multi config generator like cmake. Not sure if qt creator can work with those, but if your cmake project is set up properly, you'll be able to use `File > Open > CMake...` to simply open the project in Visual Studio which should also provide the possibility of working with the default compiler in the WSL without having to change the IDE...

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to change reconfigure the cmake, project when using a multi configuration generator. This of course assumes that the VTK package provides imported targets via `find_packag(VTK)` that properly work with different configurations. You should be able to verify this by checking the import libraries for different configurations of one of your targets in Visual Studio: there are different import libs for the Release and Debug configurations, you're good to go.

As for enabling your program to find the dlls depending on the confiruation, when using the "Play Button" (Visual Studio Debugger):

You should be able to use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) to modify `PATH` variable in the environment depending on the configuration.

The following assumes the dlls are located in `.../lib/<vtk_component_name>/(Debug|Release)` directories.

```
# should evaluate to "C:/Users/..../buildarea/.../lib"
# Note: it's very likely find_package(VTK) already provides necessary info
set(VTK_BASE_DIR "...")

set(VTK_PATH "")

foreach(VTK_COMPONENT IN ITEMS
    data-manager
    execution
    ...
)
    # use vtk Release configuration for everything but the debug config
    set(VTK_PATH "${VTK_BASE_DIR}/${VTK_COMPONENT }/$<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,Debug,Release>;${VTK_PATH}")
endforeach()

set_target_properties(my_exe PROPERTIES
    VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${VTK_PATH}$ENV{PATH}"
)
```